# How to get the user to auto fill framework setting screen pro-grammatically in android 8.0

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-settings, android-autofill-manager

I want to get the user to auto-fill framework settings screen to enable the `AutoFill` framework to auto-fill the login form in third-party apps.

So, how can I get the user programmatically to the auto-fill settings screen in *Oreo* devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search i have found answer from gitup projects.

The code to get the user to auto fill settings screen pro-grammatically is below

```
   if (mAutofillManager != null && !mAutofillManager.hasEnabledAutofillServices()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.example.android"));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for! And another question, do you know how to disable system autofill service programmatically?

Comment: You can set android:importantForAutofill = "false"

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequistes:**

User must to Enable the Autofill service.
Settings > System > Languages & input > Advanced > Input assistance > Autofill service.

**1.Providing hints for autofill**

autofill service classify the data correctly by providing the meaning of each view that could be autofillable, such as views representing usernames and passwords.

xml :

```
android:autofillHints="AUTOFILL_HINT_USERNAME"
```

or

Java    :

```
editText.setAutofillHints(View.AUTOFILL_HINT_USERNAME);
```

**2. Force an autofill request**

```
AutofillManager afm = getSystemService(AutofillManager.class);
if (afm != null) {
    if (afm.isEnabled()) {   //for afmanager is enabled or not
        afm.requestAutofill(editText);
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is, can we take the user to auto fill settings screen pro-grammatically as below for accessibility startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS));

Comment: Is it possible to check if it's enabled for a specific type, such as a phone number?

Comment: The answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2838776/happy is correct, this answer does not contain the piece of code that creates an intent to change autofill service provider.